# Spark join exponentially slow

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to make a join on two Spark RDDs. I have a transaction log which is linked to categories. I have formatted my transaction RDD to have a category id as the key.

```
transactions_cat.take(3)
[(u'707', [u'86246', u'205', u'7', u'707', u'1078778070', u'12564', u'2012-03-02 00:00:00', u'12', u'OZ', u'1', u'7.59']), 
(u'6319', [u'86246', u'205', u'63', u'6319', u'107654575', u'17876', u'2012-03-02 00:00:00', u'64', u'OZ', u'1', u'1.59']), 
(u'9753', [u'86246', u'205', u'97', u'9753', u'1022027929', u'0', u'2012-03-02 00:00:00', u'1', u'CT', u'1', u'5.99'])]

categories.take(3)
[(u'2202', 0), (u'3203', 0), (u'1726', 0)]
```

The transaction log is about 20 GB (350 millions of lines).
The category list is less than 1KB.

When I run

```
transactions_cat.join(categories).count()
```

Spark begins to be very slow. I have a stage that have 643 tasks. The first 10 tasks took about 1 min. Each tasks is then slower and slower (approximately 15 min around the 60th task). I am not sure what's wrong.

Please check theses screenshots to get a better idea.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am running Spark 1.1.0 with 4 workers using the python shell for a total Memory of 50 GB. 
Counting the transactions RDD only is quite fast (30min)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong is probably that Spark isn't noticing that you have an easy case of the join problem. When one of the two `RDD`s you're joining is so small you're better off with it not being an `RDD`. Then you can roll your own implementation of [hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join), which is actually a lot simpler than it sounds. Basically, you need to:

- Pull your category list out of the `RDD` using `collect()` -- the resulting communication will easily pay for itself (or, if possible, don't make it an `RDD` in the first place)
- Turn it into a hash table with one entry containing all the values for one key (assuming your keys are not unique)
- For each pair in your large `RDD`, look the key up in the hash table and produce one pair for each value in the list (if not found then that particular pair doesn't produce any results)

I have an [implementation in Scala](https://github.com/spirom/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/special/HashJoin.scala) -- feel free to ask questions about translating it, but it should be pretty easy.

Another interesting possibility is to try using [Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/sql/). I'm pretty sure the project's long term ambitions would include doing this for you automatically, but I don't know if they've achieved it yet.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the exact same problem albeit with dataframes. A simple join of seven 10x2 dataframes, and then running count() on the result spirals Spark out of hand with 1000+ tasks and 14 stages. Is there any way to fix/optimize this in Spark foregoing manual join?