# Joining multiple dataframes extremely slow on Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My problem is similar to one posted here ([Spark join exponentially slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238794/spark-join-exponentially-slow)), but didn't help solve mine.

In summary, I am performing a simple join on seven 10x2 toy Spark Dataframes. Data is fetched from Snowflake using Spark. 
Basically, they are all single column dataframes slapped with monotonically_increasing_id's to help with join. And it takes forever to return when I evaluate (count()) the result.

Here is the JOIN routine:

```
def combine_spark_results(results):
    # Extract first to get going
    # TODO: validations
    resultsDF = results[0]
    i = len(results)
    # Start the joining dance for rest
    for result in results[1:]:
        print(i, end=" ", flush=True)
        i -= 1
        resultsDF = resultsDF.join(result, 'id', 'outer')

    resultsDF = resultsDF.drop('id')
    return resultsDF

resultsDF = combine_spark_results(aggr_out)
```

And then the picayune mammoth:

```
resultsDF.count()
```

For some reason, running count on the perceivably simple result drives Spark berserk with 1000+ tasks across 14 stages.

[image]

As mentioned before, I am working with Snowflake on Spark that enables Pushdown Optimizations by default. Since Snowflake inserts its plan into Catalyst, it's only relevant to mention this. 
Here are the Spark-SF driver details:

Spark vr: 2.4.4
Python 3

> spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.2-spark_2.4.jar,
>   snowflake-jdbc-3.9.1.jar

I also attempted disabling pushdown but suspect it doesn't really apply (take effect).

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I missing out on something obvious?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not ```.count()``` that gets out of proportion, but your join. Spark doesn't compute your dataframe at declaration point, but when you evaluate it (you print it/write it/```.collect()``` it etc.) Am I right in saying, that what you are trying to do is to take 1 df, and join it with the same df, moved by 1 record forward (so have rec[0] joined with rec[1], rec[1] with rec[2] etc.)?

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzSkibinski. I understand lazy evaluation. And they are all different DFs - an example as simple as that.